# Cant boot Ubuntu 14.04 after dual boot with fedora 23

Tags: boot, fedora

After i installed Fedora on my computer i can no longer boot in ubuntu. When i start my computer i selcet ubuntu and hit enter.

The output says: cant read

Fedora is working fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fedora 15 still uses grub legacy for boot, and it overwrites Ubuntu's Grub 2 boot loader and menu. And Grub legacy does not find Ubuntu install out-of-the-box.

To restore Ubuntu's boot, all you have to do is re-install grub2.

Do this:

Boot using Ubuntu's Live CD
Open Nautilus, and double-click Ubuntu's partition. Take note of its mount point directory (if you labeled the partitions, it will be something like /media/label
Now open terminal and issue:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/your-ubuntu-label /dev/sda
```

You may boot into Ubuntu now.

If you want to add Fedora 15 to Ubuntu's (grub2) boot list, do this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I managed to boot ubuntu by changing the priority list in the bios. can i apply these changes now, or is it important i do it using a live cd?

Comment: I think you should be good to apply them. Please comment back with the result, because I am curious about it.